# URL rewrite fails after adding line to htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I encoutered a small problem with my .htaccess and I can't seem to fix it.

```
RewriteEngine on
# force ssl

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(apps|user)/ 
RewriteRule ^5/(.*)/(.*).html$ /~ond/index.php?id=5&page=$1&titel=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ /~ond/index.php?id=$1&titel=$2
```

The above example works flawless with an URL like: www.domain.com/123/title.html
However, I'd like to add another rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~ond/index.php?id=$1 [L]`

When I add the snippet at the bottom of my htaccess it will return the almight internal server error 500. The used URL: www.domain.com/This_Is_a_Test

What am I doing wrong? It should be a really small problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is causing 500 server error due to infinite looping. Prevent it by keeping a `RewriteCond` to allow only non-file, non-directory requests:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(apps|user)/ 
RewriteRule ^5/(.*)/(.*).html$ /~ond/index.php?id=5&page=$1&titel=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ /~ond/index.php?id=$1&titel=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /~ond/index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You just gave my mondaymorning a great start.